# php select query with where parameter error

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have written a php script to retrieve data from mysql for a particular username. The username is passed in select query and i am checking the php script using postman. Following is my php code

```
    <?php
        //getting the database connection
 require_once 'MyDbConnect.php';

 //an array to display response
 $response = array();

 //if it is an api call
 //that means a get parameter named api call is set in the URL
 //and with this parameter we are concluding that it is an api call
 if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

 switch($_GET['apicall']){
   case 'getSpecificData':
     case 'getSpecificData':
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('your_username'))){
//getting values
$your_username = $_POST['your_username'];

$heroes = array();
$sql = "SELECT your_username,your_mobile,referral_name,referral_contact,referral_email,
loan_type,loan_amount  FROM mytable WHERE your_username = ? ";
$sql->bind_param("s",$your_username);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($your_username, $your_mobile,$referral_name,$referral_contact,
$referral_email,$loan_type,$loan_amount);

//looping through all the records
while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = [
 'your_username'=>$your_username,
 'your_mobile'=>$your_mobile,
 'referral_name'=>$referral_name,
 'referral_contact'=>$referral_contact,
 'referral_email'=>$referral_email,
 'loan_type'=>$loan_type,
 'loan_amount'=>$loan_amount
 ];

 //pushing the array inside the hero array
 array_push($heroes, $temp);

}
echo json_encode($heroes);
}
break;

default:
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
}
}
else{
//if it is not api call
//pushing appropriate values to response array
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
}

function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

 //traversing through all the parameters
 foreach($params as $param){
 //if the paramter is not available
 if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
 //return false
 return false;
 }
 }
 //return true if every param is available
 return true;
 }
?>
```

The problem is in the select query. When i write the select query as i mentioned above in my php code i get nothing. but if i write the select query as follows i get proper data

$sql = "SELECT your_username,your_mobile,referral_name,referral_contact,referral_email,
    loan_type,loan_amount  FROM mytable WHERE your_username = 'Rohan' ";

Can somebody please explain me the cause of error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the binding of the variable:

```
//  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$your_username);
```

Is already in your code. Change it to:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s",$your_username);
```

The "s" indicates the variable is a string, the binding "replaces" the "?" in the query.

EDIT:
Than use this snippet instead ;)

```
$your_username = $_POST['your_username'];

      //creating the query
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,your_username,your_mobile,referral_name,referral_contact,referral_email,
loan_type,loan_amount FROM mytable WHERE your_username = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$your_username);
```

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong code can you please have a look. I have edited the question